# How to get Annotate gem to work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, annotate

I've included `annotate-models` in my `:development` group, removed `Gemfile.lock`, ran `bundle install`, and still *it breaks*.

```
$ annotate User
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby-enterprise-edition/2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/polyglot-0.3.1/lib/polyglot.rb:64:in `polyglot_original_require': no such file to load -- annotate/annotate_models (LoadError)
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby-enterprise-edition/2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/polyglot-0.3.1/lib/polyglot.rb:64:in `require'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby-enterprise-edition/2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby-enterprise-edition/2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby-enterprise-edition/2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby-enterprise-edition/2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby-enterprise-edition/2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby-enterprise-edition/2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/annotate-2.4.0/lib/tasks/annotate_models.rake:3
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby-enterprise-edition/2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby-enterprise-edition/2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby-enterprise-edition/2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby-enterprise-edition/2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby-enterprise-edition/2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby-enterprise-edition/2010.02/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby-enterprise-edition/2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby-enterprise-edition/2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby-enterprise-edition/2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/annotate-2.4.0/bin/annotate:67
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby-enterprise-edition/2010.02/bin/annotate:19:in `load'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby-enterprise-edition/2010.02/bin/annotate:19
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you running this from the command prompt? If so try `bundle exec annotate User` to use your bundled gems rather than the system gems.

And is the gem called 'annotate' or 'annotate-models'?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be `annotate` gem? Its github repo is called `annotate_models`.

`annotate-models` gem is different and hasn't been updated for a while.

Comment: yea it should be `annotate` not `annotate-models`